# Button has a weird border around it, how do I get rid of it?

Tags: html, css

[Here is how it looks from my source files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHtce.png)

[And here is how it looks from where it is hosted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gmU8.png)

Obviously alot wrong with it but the one thing I'm most worried about is that border around the blue button.

Here's the HTML code for each button.

## Blue Button

```
<a href="#" ><button  class="btn" type="button">View The Line Up</button></a>
```

## Grey Button

```
<a href="#" ><button  class="btn2" type="button">View The Line Up!</button></a>
```

---

and the CSS.

## Blue Button

```
.btn {

  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #358cb1;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

## Grey Button

```
.btn2 {
  -webkit-border-radius: 31;
  -moz-border-radius: 31;
  border-radius: 31px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  border: solid #000000 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.btn2:hover {
    background: #acb0b3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `<button>` in a link tag `a`?

Comment: There is not need to use `Button` tag with `a `tag you can simply apply all css property on `a` tag you used on `button` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you want exactly but why are you wrapping an `<a>` tag around a `<button>` ? try this as in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cpvgmms8/)

```
<a href="" class="btn">View The Line Up</a>
<a href="" class="btn2">View The Line Up!</a>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I've never used buttons before and I am very new to any type of programming. Thanks again.

Comment: HTML button elements have default styling to them (background and border) that you will need to override.

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad it helped, there are many resources over the web which can help you learning better and faster https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML .. 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp .. as well as videos on youtube

Answer (score 3):

If you want a solid, single-colour border, then:

```
border-style: solid;
```

It looks like it's set to something like `inset` or `outset` which are meant to create a quasi-3D effect, Windows 98-style.

If you don't want any border at all, then:

```
border: 0;
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EjvbvfM.png That makes it look like this. EDIT: Mi-Creativity found a solution.

Comment: Ah, alright, you don't want any border at all. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`border:none;` will get rid of the border.

As an aside, having a button inside of a link sounds redundant. Why not style the link instead (and apply `display:inline-block;`)?

```
<a href="#" class="btn">My button text</a>
```